# How to make a change by moving phone

Tags: java, android

I want to develop a game like head's up !
what I need is , when the user moves down the phone ,some functions get called , how to code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **RxSensor** which is reactive wrapper for android sensors. It can be found here https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3350

---

Android has a collection of sensors at [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors) and [Motion Sensor Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion).

---

Sample Usage with **RxSensor** and Android Motion Documentation
Take for example Sensor `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`

```
     RxSensor rxSensor = new RxSensor(this);
    //Note where i have put TYPE_ACCELEROMETER
    rxSensor.observe(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<RxSensorEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() { }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) { }

            @Override
            public void onNext(RxSensorEvent sensorEvent) {
                Log.d("RxSensor", "event: " + sensorEvent.toString());
            }
        });
```

`TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`

> Acceleration force along the x axis (including gravity).

```
TYPE_ACCELEROMETER_UNCALIBRATED
```

> Measured acceleration along the X axis without any bias compensation and many more types if you look at the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You have to sample sensors data, specifically the accelerometer (you also can take gyro data for pitch, etc.)

[example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/sensor/android-accelerometer-example/).